# Append an element from a list to another list

Tags: python, list, coordinates, element

Good day. I need your help guys. I have two lists shown below.

```
List_1= [
    'Sta     Pno     Azimuth      Distance     Latitude     Departure ', 
    'T1      X       170.7011111   22.236       21.9438      -3.593    ', 
    'T1      X       170.0        20.0         19.6962      -3.473    ', 
    'T2      X       30.22833333   6.083        -5.2559      -3.0625   ', 
    'T3      X       154.5155556   98.212       88.6562      -42.2573  ', 
    'T4      CHB     351.4977778   93.637       -92.6079     13.844    ', 
    '' ]

List_2= [
    'Sta     Northing     Easting   ', 
    'T1      2000         2000      ',
    'T2      1500         1600      ', 
    'T3      2400         2200      ', 
    'T4      2600         2800      ', 
    '' ]
```

i want to attach the northing and easting of the stations to the first list. Please help. So far i tried to use the zip function and then to combine the two lists but the problem is ihave no idea how to match an element to another element by using a part of an element as reference for matching to the other element.

Comment: You should go through the section of how to ask a question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and be more specific about something that you are stuck on. SO is not a website to get people to write code for you.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Im sorry ill edit my question.. This is my first time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# deal with headings separately from rest of data.
# also split each heading into a list of string rather than single string.
l1_headings, l2_headings = List_1.pop(0).split(), List_2.pop(0).split()
# put each row of List_1 in a list of dictionary using headings as keys
l1_dicts = [{k:v for k, v in zip(l1_headings, row.split())} for row in List_1 if row != '']
# put each row of List_2 in a dictionary of dictionaries indexed by 'Sta'
l2_by_Sta = {}
for row in List_2:
    if row == '': continue
    d = {k:v for k, v in zip(l2_headings, row.split())}
    l2_by_Sta[d['Sta']] = d
# update l1_dicts from data in l2_by_Sta
for d in l1_dicts:
    d.update(l2_by_Sta[d['Sta']])
```

`l1_dicts` now contains:

```
[{'Azimuth': '170.7011111',
  'Departure': '-3.593',
  'Distance': '22.236',
  'Easting': '2000',
  'Latitude': '21.9438',
  'Northing': '2000',
  'Pno': 'X',
  'Sta': 'T1'},
 {'Azimuth': '170.0',
  'Departure': '-3.473',
  'Distance': '20.0',
  'Easting': '2000',
  'Latitude': '19.6962',
  'Northing': '2000',
  'Pno': 'X',
  'Sta': 'T1'},
 {'Azimuth': '30.22833333',
  'Departure': '-3.0625',
  'Distance': '6.083',
  'Easting': '1600',
  'Latitude': '-5.2559',
  'Northing': '1500',
  'Pno': 'X',
  'Sta': 'T2'},
 {'Azimuth': '154.5155556',
  'Departure': '-42.2573',
  'Distance': '98.212',
  'Easting': '2200',
  'Latitude': '88.6562',
  'Northing': '2400',
  'Pno': 'X',
  'Sta': 'T3'},
 {'Azimuth': '351.4977778',
  'Departure': '13.844',
  'Distance': '93.637',
  'Easting': '2800',
  'Latitude': '-92.6079',
  'Northing': '2600',
  'Pno': 'CHB',
  'Sta': 'T4'}]
```

If you need to write this data to a text file use `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly. Thank you! I was planning to convert it to a list of dictionaries but unfortunately i cant come up with a code that will give results just like what you did. Im really greatful sir. Thank you so much.